# $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq I_n\implies |A|\leq n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

---

**My attempt:**

> **Lemma:** Let $I_n=\{i\in\mathbb N\mid 1\leq i\leq n\},\emptyset\neq A\subseteq I_n$. Then $A$ has a greatest element.

Let $U=\{u\in\Bbb N\mid a\leq u\space\forall a\in A\}$ and $u'$ be the least element of $U$. If $u'=1$, then $A=\{1\}$, and therefore $1$ is the greatest element of $A$. If $u'>1$, then $u'=c+1$ for some $c\in\Bbb N$. Suppose that $u'\notin A$, then $u'>a\space\forall a\in A\implies c+1>a\space\forall a\in A\implies c\geq a\space\forall a\in A\implies c\in U$ (this contradicts the minimality of $u'$). Thus $u'\in A$, and consequently $u'$ is the greatest element of $A$.$\blacksquare$

> **Theorem:** Let $I_n=\{p\in\mathbb N\mid 1\leq p\leq n\},\emptyset\neq A\subseteq I_n$. Then $A$ is finite, $|A|\leq n$, with equality if and only if $A=I_n$.

We will prove this theorem by induction on $n$. It's trivial that the theorem is true for $n=1$. Assume that the theorem is true for all $n\leq k$. For $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq I_{k+1}$ and by **Lemma**, let $a'$ be the greatest element of $A$. There are two possible cases in total.

1. $A$ is a singleton. Then $A=\{1\}\implies |A|=1\leq n$ and $A$ is finite.
2. $A$ is not a singleton. Let $B=A-\{a'\}$, then $\emptyset\neq B\subseteq I_k\implies B$ is finite and $|B|\leq k\implies$ there exists a bijection $f:I_t\to B$ where $|B|=t\leq k$. We define a bijection $g:A\to I_{t+1}$ as follows: $g(a)=f(a)\space\forall a\in B$ and $g(a')=t+1$. Thus $A$ is finite and $|A|=t+1\leq k+1$.

$|A|=k+1\Leftrightarrow t=k\Leftrightarrow B=I_k\Leftrightarrow A=I_k\cup\{a'\}\Leftrightarrow A=I_{k+1}$.

By principle of strong induction, the theorem is proved.$\blacksquare$

Comment: How do you define $\mathbb N$ (or, how do you establish that strong induction is a valid inference principle)?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I learned $\Bbb N$ and Principle of Strong Induction before, so I assume those things.

Comment: That is not quite what I am asking. The point is that if you are going through the trouble of spelling out all these details,  it is kind of awkward that the key piece of the argument does not even grant a passing comment (or a link to a previous answer, or a reference to a book).